# Adding Multiple Presenters to ArrayObjectAdapter of Android Leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to display two different types of cards in the same row `(ListRow)`.

I tried to modify the Presenter class by adding viewType similar to dealing with displaying multiple row types in `RecyclerVew` but it did not work.

I tried digging into the Presenter and `ArrayObjectAdapter` code but there is no obvious option to achieve this. If someone has done this then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: May we see what you have tried, and/or what code you'd be integrating this with?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Holidays and all. Essentially my problem stemmed from lack of understanding the API. I tried to override the Presenter class without taking a look at ClassPresentorSelector. The accepted answer showed me where to look. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ClassPresenterSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ClassPresenterSelector.html) to show different types of cards in the same row

[Example](https://github.com/3sidedcube/Android-TV-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/cube/androidtvdemo/fragment/MyDetailsFragment.java#L48)

```
ClassPresenterSelector selector = new ClassPresenterSelector();

YourDetailTypePresenter detailPresenter = new YourDetailTypePresenter();
YourImageTypePresenter imagePresenter = new YourImageTypePresenter();

selector.addClassPresenter(DetailsOverviewRow.class, detailPresenter);
selector.addClassPresenter(ImageOverviewRow.class, imagePresenter);

mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(selector);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this class. I completely missed this while exploring the library. I have accepted this answer.